# /questions/{id}/answers missing title attribute

Tags: bug, status-completed

http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/help/method?method=questions/{id}/answers (it won't linkify properly!):

```
"title": {
  "description": "title of this post, in plaintext",
  "values": "string",
  "optional": false,
  "suggested_buffer_size": 200
}
```

http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/questions/4072963/answers (for example):

```
{
  "total": 1,
  "page": 1,
  "pagesize": 30,
  "answers": [
    {
      "answer_id": 4073003,
      "accepted": false,
      "answer_comments_url": "/answers/4073003/comments",
      "question_id": 4072963,
      "owner": {
        "user_id": 21755,
        "user_type": "registered",
        "display_name": "Paul",
        "reputation": 7231,
        "email_hash": "8d1dc85bd2d8ed3a2074b9728fbdaa55"
      },
      "creation_date": 1288645283,
      "last_activity_date": 1288645283,
      "up_vote_count": 0,
      "down_vote_count": 0,
      "view_count": 0,
      "score": 0,
      "community_owned": false
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see, there's no `title` attribute in there. This is breaking Droidstack. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed.

In hindsight, it's not really correct to return `title` on answers... so this will probably go away in the next version.

Kind of depends, really.  I see how it would be useful to have it returned, *once*, so you can title an answer collection.  On every answer its pretty overkill.  Hmmm.

Comment: Yeah, I thought that, too, at some point. But since now Droidstack is powered by StackWrap4J which throws an exception when there's no `title` attribute, it was kind of a blocker :) thanks!

Comment: Actually, it makes **a lot** of sense for calls such as `/questions/{id};{id}/answers`. I don't think you'll be able to take it out :)